# Extends the terms calculation

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to extend the calculation of terms for invoices (Field TermsID, on Bills and Ajustments screen (AP301000)

The standard behaviour of Acumatica is : When you update the termsID field, it automatically updates the dueDate field and the discountDate field

So my idea was to look at the code in APInvoiceEntry and look for the TermsID_FieldUpdated

```
protected virtual void APInvoice_TermsID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    Terms terms = (Terms)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<APInvoice.termsID>(sender, e.Row);

    if (terms != null && terms.InstallmentType != TermsInstallmentType.Single)
    {
        foreach (APAdjust adj in Adjustments.Select())
        {
            Adjustments.Cache.Delete(adj);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesnt seem to do anything except delete the cache of the adjustments. And I dont know what to extend in order to add another way of calculating the terms dates.

(The goal is to allow the following calculation : 
- I take the invoice date, add 30 days, if i'm below the 10th day of the next month, i set the due date to the 10th day of the next month, else I set the due date to the 10th day of the next next month).

Thanks,

Comment: Ultimately, what fields are you trying to modify, APInvoice.dueDate and APInvoice.discDate?

Comment: Also, for which document type do you want to modify DueDate? I'm asking because most of the logic seem to apply only for Prepayment.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to modify both these fields, but instead of rewriting the logic behind the terms behaviour I wanted to reutilize It, but I fail to find how the termsID is used to update duedate and discDate.

I want it to work mainly for bills. (Bills and adjustments screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a FieldUpdated event handler on DueDate and examined the call stack to find the method which modify DueDate:
[image]

It's the [Terms(...)] attribute that contains the logic:

```
#region TermsID
public abstract class termsID : IBqlField
{
}

/// <summary>
/// The <see cref="PX.Objects.CS.Terms">credit terms</see> associated with the document (unavailable for prepayments and debit adjustments).\
/// Defaults to the <see cref="Vendor.TermsID">credit terms of the vendor</see>.
/// </summary>
[PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<Vendor.termsID,
    Where<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<Current<APInvoice.vendorID>>,
        And<Current<APInvoice.docType>, NotEqual<APDocType.debitAdj>>>>),
    PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Terms", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[APTermsSelector]
[Terms(typeof(APInvoice.docDate), typeof(APInvoice.dueDate), typeof(APInvoice.discDate), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt), typeof(APInvoice.curyOrigDiscAmt))]
public virtual string TermsID
{
    get;
    set;
}
#endregion
```

Inside the Terms attribute you'll find the code modifying due date. 
You could look into providing a custom attribute or bypassing that logic.

```
public static void CalcTermsDates(Terms terms, DateTime? docDate, out DateTime? dueDate, out DateTime? discDate)
{
    dueDate = null;
    discDate = null;
    if (docDate != null && terms != null)
    {
        DateTime DocDate = docDate.Value;
        switch (terms.DueType)
        {
            case TermsDueType.FixedNumberOfDays:
                dueDate = DocDate.AddDays((double)terms.DayDue00);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.Prox:
                DateTime sameDayOfNextMonth = DocDate.AddMonths(1);
                DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(sameDayOfNextMonth.Year, sameDayOfNextMonth.Month, 1);
                dueDate = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays((double)terms.DayDue00);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfNextMonth:
                dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue00).AddMonths(1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfTheMonth:
                int monthShift = DocDate.Day > (int)terms.DayDue00 ? 1 : 0;
                dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue00).AddMonths(monthShift);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.Custom:
                int nextmonth = 0;
                if (DocDate.Day >= terms.DayFrom00 && DocDate.Day <= terms.DayTo00)
                {
                    if (terms.DayDue00 <= terms.DayTo00)
                    {
                        nextmonth = 1;
                    }
                    dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue00).AddMonths(nextmonth);
                }
                if (DocDate.Day >= terms.DayFrom01 && DocDate.Day <= terms.DayTo01)
                {
                    if (terms.DayDue01 <= terms.DayTo01)
                    {
                        nextmonth = 1;
                    }
                    dueDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDue01).AddMonths(nextmonth);
                }
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfMonth:
                dueDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfNextMonth:
                dueDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (terms.InstallmentType == TermsInstallmentType.Multiple)
        {
            discDate = dueDate;
        }
        else
        {
        switch (terms.DiscType)
        {
            case TermsDueType.FixedNumberOfDays:
                discDate = DocDate.AddDays((double)terms.DayDisc);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.Prox:
                DateTime sameDayOfNextMonth = DocDate.AddMonths(1);
                DateTime firstDayOfNextMonth = new DateTime(sameDayOfNextMonth.Year, sameDayOfNextMonth.Month, 1);
                discDate = firstDayOfNextMonth.AddDays((double)terms.DayDisc);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfNextMonth:
                discDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDisc).AddMonths(1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.DayOfTheMonth:
                int monthShift;

                    if (terms.DueType == TermsDueType.DayOfNextMonth && DocDate.Day <= (int)terms.DayDue00)
                        monthShift = DocDate.Day >= (int)terms.DayDisc ? 1 : 0;
                else if (terms.DueType == TermsDueType.EndOfNextMonth)
                    monthShift = DocDate.Day >= (int)terms.DayDisc ? 1 : 0;
                else
                    monthShift = DocDate.Day > (int)terms.DayDue00 ? 1 : 0;
                discDate = new PXDateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, (int)terms.DayDisc).AddMonths(monthShift);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfMonth:
                discDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            case TermsDueType.EndOfNextMonth:
                discDate = new DateTime(DocDate.Year, DocDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        }

        if (discDate > dueDate)
        {
            discDate = dueDate;
        }
    }           
}
```

You can create a new attribute (ex: MyTerms) deriving from an existing one (ex: Terms) and override methods (ex: CalcTerms). You then redefine/extend the field that is using that attribute (TermsID) so it uses your attribute (MyTerms) instead of (Terms).

The **major issue** is when the code you want to change is in methods that can't be overridden, in that case you need to copy paste the code wholesale in your custom attribute and forgo inheritance.

The starting point for that is the Attribute Code. To get it, use VIEW SOURCE feature in customization project editor:
[image]

Then use 'Find in files' to get the attribute code:
[image]

Comment: This is totaly what I was looking for, I suppose there's no framework items TermsAttributeExtension the same way there's a PXGraphExtension ?

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how you can go about overriding/extending Attributes.

Comment: You can also check example in framework source code like SOInvoiceTermsAttribute by searching for: public class SOInvoiceTermsAttribute : TermsAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Implement a APInvoice_DueDate_FieldUpdated event handler, it will be raised when the term is changed.

Comment: My question was more about : where is the eventhandler that take cares of the calculation of the dueDate when the terms field is updated so I can extend it.

I know how I could just add an eventhandler on the termsID field and check if it's equal to some hard coded value and then set the duedate as i want, but I feel like it's both ugly and inefficient because not reusing the framework's ressources

Comment: In some cases value changes will raise the FieldUpdated event making it an excellent place to start debugging. You can examine the call stack and work your way back to the initial event that triggered the value change.